# Problema al cargar una imagen en un ListView en Android/Java

Tags: java, android

Estoy teniendo problemas para cargar una imagen en un ListView de una aplicación Android escrita en Java y XML.

activity_guia.xml

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="40dp">
    </ListView>
```

que a su vez tiene una ImageView entre sus items:

listItem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tvw1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:background="@drawable/redondeo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#4d4d4d"  />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tw1"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/im1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Tengo almacenadas en la carpeta drawable las imagenes de 180 minerales en tamaño grande y pequeño. La grande sería `oro.png` y la pequeña `oro2.png`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la clase que carga el ListView trato de obtener la imagen pequeña para cargarla junto al nombre del mineral, su grupo mineral y la foto pequeña.

ListViewAdapter.java

```
package com.geologyappliacions.minerals;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<MineralesAdapater.Minerales> items;
    private float dpWidth;

    ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<MineralesAdapater.Minerales> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Set data into the view.
        ImageView ivItem = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.im1);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvw1);
        TextView tvTitle2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tw1);

        MineralesAdapater.Minerales item = this.items.get(position);

        tvTitle.setText(item.getNombre().toUpperCase());
        tvTitle2.setText(item.getTipo().toUpperCase());

        if ((item.getTipo().equals("Elementos nativos.")) || 
(item.getTipo().equals("Native elements.")) || (item.getTipo().equals("Éléments 
natifs.")) || (item.getTipo().equals("Elementi nativi."))) {
            tvTitle2.setBackgroundColor(0xFFB3D2D7);
        }
        if ((item.getTipo().equals("Sulfuros y sulfosales.")) || 
(item.getTipo().equals("Sulfides and sulfosalts.")) || 
(item.getTipo().equals("Sulfures et sulfosels.")) || (item.getTipo().equals("Solfuri 
e solfosali."))) {
            tvTitle2.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF1E4AE);
        }
        if ((item.getTipo().equals("Óxidos e hidróxidos.")) || 
(item.getTipo().equals("Oxides and hydroxides.")) || (item.getTipo().equals("Oxydes 
et hydroxydes.")) || (item.getTipo().equals("Ossidi e idrossidi."))) {
            tvTitle2.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE2B2EE);
        }
//Omito el color del resto de grupos
        int id = rowView.getResources().getIdentifier("com.geologyapplications.minerals:drawable/"
            + item.getImagen() + "2", null, null);
        ivItem.setImageResource(id);
  

    return rowView;
}

}
```

Las líneas `int id = rowView.getResources().getIdentifier("com.geologyapplications.minerals:drawable/" + item.getImagen() + "2", null, null);` y `ivItem.setImageResource(id);` no funcionan según lo esperado, no carga la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la clase que adapta los minerales, para comprender cómo funciona el código.

MineralsAdapter.java

```
package com.geologyappliacions.minerals;

import java.util.ArrayList;


class MineralesAdapater {
    //clase que adapta la ruta views con todos los valores en una fila de
    //en un vector de vectores

    private ArrayList<Minerales> minerales = new ArrayList<Minerales>();

    public ArrayList<Minerales> getMinerales() {
        return minerales;
    }

    public void setMinerales(ArrayList<Minerales> minerales) {
        this.minerales = minerales;
    }

    final static class Minerales {

        private String id, Nombre, Tipo, Color, Imagen;
        
        public Minerales(String id, String Nombre, String Tipo, String Color, String 
        Imagen) {
            this.id = id;
            this.Nombre = Nombre;
            this.Tipo = Tipo;
            this.Color = Color;
            this.Imagen = Imagen;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return Nombre;
        }

        public String getTipo() {
            return Tipo;
        }

        public String getColor() {
            return Color;
        }

        public String getImagen() {
            return Imagen;
        }
    }
}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal y cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el nombre del paquete que por error llamé geologyappliacions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.geologyappliacions.minerals">
```

Cambiando la línea:

```
int id = rowView.getResources().getIdentifier("com.geologyappliacions.minerals:drawable/"+item.getNombre()+"2", null, null);
```

el código funciona y carga las imágenes. La otra es renombrar el paquete de la aplicación por el correcto.

Disculpen este error tipográfico. Si quieren pueden sugerirme que borre la pregunta, no sé qué es lo correcto en estos casos.